# How to reduce the width of Clarity accordion component?

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I am trying to add accordion component to my page. But the width of the accordion component is too long. In fact, if I move it a little bit to right I can't even see the right border.

How can I change the width of the accordion border? I am using exact code provided [here](https://v2.clarity.design/accordion#examples). And it looks like this:
[image: this]

Comment: Show the code of the css and html of accordion you have set

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

1. put the accordion inside a container element that has width set on it
2. Add a css class to the `clr-accordion` that has a width set on it

Here are some code examples:

```
  <section class="accordion-width">
    <h3>Accordion in a container with width set</h3>
    <clr-accordion>
      ...
    </clr-accordion>
  </section>

  <h3>Accordion with width class directly on the element:</h3>
    <clr-accordion class="accordion-width">
      ...
    </clr-accordion>
```

With a style similar to this:

```
.accordion-width {
  width: 200px;
}
```

You can see working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58505545-accordion-widths

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by adding `style="position:relative; width:360px "` into the `<clr-accordion-panel>'`. If you can add this to your answer I will accept it.  So, it looks like this: ```<clr-accordion>
    <clr-accordion-panel style="position:relative; width:360px ">
        <clr-accordion-title>Item 1</clr-accordion-title>
        <clr-accordion-content *clrIfExpanded>Content 1</clr-accordion-content>
    </clr-accordion-panel>
</clr-accordion>```

Comment: I would recommend the using a parent container constraint or constraining the `clr-accordion ` element rather than each of the panels. While adding a width to the panel, I'm hesitant to recommend it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in css only by giving it a width using a calc function to set it to the with in percent as 80 percent and aligning it to the right